# E- visa New Zealand, passport number change

Tags: visas

I had to get another passport due to my current one only having three pages.

Have an E-visa linked to old passport, will I have to travel with old passport or update e-visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply to transfer your visa to your new passport.

The relevant [Immigration NZ web page](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/transferring-my-visa-to-a-new-passport) says this:

> Working Holiday Visas, e-visas and other label-less visas which have
>   been issued electronically (without a label) are recorded against the
>   passport number at the time of your application.
>
> If you get a new passport issued, you must inform us, so that your
>   records can be updated, and you can continue to use the label-less
>   visa for your travel to and from New Zealand.

The process for applying for a transfer is detailed on the same page. It's free for labelless visas.